# Auth0 loginWithPopup() authenticates user but not loginWithRedirect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, auth0

I am setting up Auth0 in a React app and am running into a bit of confusion.

Inside an Auth0 context I defined, I have a function called `login`:

```
  const login = async (options) => {

    await auth0Client.loginWithPopup(options); // isAuthenticated() returns true
    // OR
    await auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(options); // isAuthenticated() returns false

    const isAuthenticated = await auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
    console.log(isAuthenticated);

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
      const claims = await auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims();
      const authToken = claims.__raw;

      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN',
        payload: {
          authToken,
          user: {
            id: user.sub,
            avatar: user.picture,
            email: user.email,
            name: user.name,
            tier: 'Premium'
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

In the above function, I currently have `auth0Client.loginWithPopup(options)` implemented and this works correctly (i.e. `auth0Client.isAuthenticated()` returns `true` in the following line which redirects the user into the app).

I would like to use `auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(options)` instead, but when I run my app with this line, `auth0Client.isAuthenticated()` returns `false` and the user isn't redirected away from the login page. The redirect window opens, however, letting me type in my credentials, but once I submit, it goes back to the login page.

Please help! What am I missing here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?